# How to create a HTML layout with selectos in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML, needed for a popup modal window:

```
<div id="modal-overlay">
    <a href="#" class="modal-close">[close]</a>
</div>

<div id="modal">
    <div id="modal-content">
        <div id="modal-image"></div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="modal-prev">previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="modal-next">next</a>
</div>
```

I've tested all and works correctly!

Now, i want to create that layout dynamically in jQuery (since the modal window is going to be use in many web pages). Also i want to select some parts of my layout in jQuery, like, for example:

```
var content = $('#modal-content');
var image = $('#modal-image');
var next = $('.modal-next');
var prev = $('.modal-prev');
var close = $('.modal-close');
```

I started doing something like this:

```
var overlay = '<div id="modal-overlay"></div>';

$(document).ready(function(){

    // add the mask for modal window
    $('body').append(overlay);

    // assign it to a selector
    var overlay = $('#modal-overlay');

    // 
});
```

But, i don't feel that it's the right way to achieve what i'm looking for... i feel like i'm doing spaghetty coding.

Is there a way to create the layout in jquery in a more intelligent way?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "_create the layout in jquery with the selectors_"?

Comment: @undefined: i mean create the HTML layout above and attach it to the <body>. I get your question, ive edited my post so it clearer. sorry

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching in google as I'm sure you did before asking and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217409/jquery-best-practice-for-creating-complex-html-fragments) as the first result searching 'best practices for creating tags in jquery'.

Comment: yeah, i'm reading all there is to know about the subject, i feel like im trying to be too fancy and maybe i'm forgetting about performance. Since i'm doing all this in PHP, i will create the layout in a php page and include it using include... simple and best for perfomance.

Answer (score -1):

You might represent your div structure as a JS object (ie. `` `div: {..{div:etc}..} ``, and then add a custom constructor object to your JSON instal via jQuery.extend to print it as html (ie.

`for element in modal.scheme: //whatever best suits your data, either compile a string and use $(selector).html() or by .append()`.